# sorting data bound to svg elements using d3.js

Tags: javascript, svg, d3.js

in sum, the problem here is that the svg markup (viewed w/ my browser dev tools) of my
rendered code does indeed show the desired markup element-data binding; however, that binding is not reflected in the rendered view.

***context***:
i have built a *grid* (an m x n matrix of square cells) in which each cell is rendered 
as an *svg rect*; the data is a json array of objects, one object per cell; each object is 
comprised of a number of properties; the value of one of these properties i render
as a label (svg "text" element) vislble within the face of each cell.

the initial rendering is fine-does exactly what i want it to do.

i just added a widget (simple button) that calls a *sort* function.

when this button is clicked, i can see that that *the sort itself is working* by looking
at the *markup*--ie, after clicking the sort button, the labels, as shown in the markup below, are now in the correct sort order:

```
<text id="labels" fill="white" x="140" y="222" text-anchor="middle">122.23</text>
<text id="labels" fill="white" x="304" y="304" text-anchor="middle">135.08</text>
<text id="labels" fill="white" x="304" y="222" text-anchor="middle">141.53</text>
<text id="labels" fill="white" x="222" y="140" text-anchor="middle">195.79</text>
<text id="labels" fill="white" x="222" y="222" text-anchor="middle">244.42</text>
<text id="labels" fill="white" x="222" y="304" text-anchor="middle">255.21</text>
<text id="labels" fill="white" x="304" y="140" text-anchor="middle">258.16</text>
```

yet this sort is not reflected in the ***rendered*** ***labels***.

the probelem has to be in my sort function (sortByPropertyX), which is here:

```
var sortOrder = false;

var sortByPropertyX = function() {
        sortOrder = !sortOrder;
        sortCells = function(x, y) {
    if (sortOrder) {
        return x.someProperty - y.someProperty;
    }
        return y.someProperty - x.someProperty;
        };
        svg.selectAll("rects")
    .sort(sortCells)
    .attr("x", function(d, i) {return d.x})
    .attr("y", function(d, i) {return d.y})

        svg.selectAll("text")
    .sort(sortCells)
    .text(function(d, i) {
        return d.someProperty;
    })
    .attr("text-anchor", "middle")
    .attr("x", function(d, i) {
        return d.x + CELLWIDTH/2;
            })
    .attr("y", function(d, i) {
        return d.y + CELLHEIGHT/2;
    })
```

Comment: You would need to specify this sort order when adding the elements. All you're doing in the code above is change the order in which the elements are processed, not the order in which they are displayed.

Comment: Could you sort your data in a javascript function and then rebind to the SVG elements through an update()?

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you're positioning the rects based on `x` and `y` values that are in the raw data:

```
.attr("x", function(d, i) {return d.x})
.attr("y", function(d, i) {return d.y})
```

When you re-sort the data, these `x` and `y` values are staying the same. Nothing about resorting affects them. And, just resorting the DOM elements isn't going to reposition these rects, which use explicit "x" and "y" attributes for positioning.

You'd need to update these `x` and `y` values to something that reflects the new sorting. Or, if the rects' positioning is to be based entirely on the sort order, then you need to change the returned values to be functions of `i` –– each datum's index within the sorted array –– rather than something that's in the raw data.